# How can we redirect request based on context path

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I have setup 2 aem on my local in which one aem is running on context path ex:/abc.
how can we filter request on dispather based on context path.
Example : if request is /index.html it should be redirected to AEM 1.
if request is /abc/request.html it should be redirected to AEM 2.

Comment: If you have load balancer in between Dispatcher and Publish server then you can configure Load balancer with your rule.

Comment: It is the same site? Because even the dispatcher is able to perform load balancing, it seems better here to have a separate dispatcher for each publish instance and delegating the rule to a proper load balancer

Comment: For user it will look its getting served from same domain but in background one QS is running on context path so request having context path will be served from this QS.
Need to have common dispatcher for both QS. Where should i make entry in dispatcher config